# How I made the XJC ant task use more than one bindings file?

Tags: java, ant, jaxb, gradle, xjc

I am trying to use the XJC ant task to generate some classes in a gradle script. I have no problem to generate them if I use only one bindings file (for class renaming0, but I soon as I try to use more (an episode file), they are royally ignored by the task.

To be more clear, this

```
ant.xjc(schema : 'test.xsd',
        destdir:'destdir',
        extension: true,
        package: 'testpackage') {
    classpath { 
        fileset(dir: project.property('jaxb.home'), includes: 'jaxb-impl.jar') // <== here I include the 
    }
    binding(dir: project.projectDir) {
        filename(name:'bindings.xml') //<== this bindings is for classes renaming
        //filename(name:'previous.episode') //<== this bindings is for classes reusage
    }
    arg(value:"-npa")
    arg(value:"-nv")
}
```

works nicely, the classes are renamed just fine, but as soon as I try to include the previous.episode file, the two bindings file are ignored : no more renaming, and of course, no reusage

What's drive me crazy is that calling XJC with the cmd line `xjc -nv -classpath "<haxb.home>jaxb-impl.jar" -d destdir -p testpackage -b bindings.xml -b previous.episode -extension  -npa` work like a charm.

Additionnaly, if I merge bindings.xml and previous.episode, it also work, but it's not very practical, to say the least.

So if someone could help me on this point, it would be wonderful.

Answer (score -1):

[gradle-jaxb-plugin](https://github.com/jacobono/gradle-jaxb-plugin) allows for using multiple binding files:

```
jaxb 
{
  xsdDir = "schemas"
  bindingsDir = "bindings"
  bindings = ["SampleBinding.xjb", "AnotherOne.xjb"]
  xjc 
  {
    taskClassname = "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJC2Task"
    generatePackage = "com.my.application.schema"
  }
}
```

On the other hand, it requires to specify an XSD folder instead of a particular file, and parses all schemas inside of that folder. However, it is easy to bypass the issue and so far it was the only one problem with the plugin which I had.